# Mongo query take a long time. How make it more fast?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I use mongoose driver in node js. My schema:

```
let sendResultSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  emailId: String,      email: String,              
  letterId: String,     sendedFrom: String,
  resultMsg: String,    owner: String,              
  created: Date,        result: Boolean,
  tag: String,          tryNum: Number,
  clickHash: String,    links: [String]
})
sendResultSchema.index({emailId: 1, letterId: 1, result: 1, owner: 1, tag: 1, clickHash: 1})
let sendResultModel = mongoose.model('sendresult', sendResultSchema)
```

sendresult collection have a 641000 documents.

this query executing ~0.5 seconds.

```
 db.sendresults.find({"tag" : "tagValue", "letterId" : "5ad630b5949bb02ea07d15d1"}).sort({emailId: -1}).limit(1)
```

I think it must execute more fast. You can see explain of this query [here](https://gist.github.com/tolyanor/64360d648f3fc89f73648aed1e16f230)

How make this query more fast?

Comment: `sendResultSchema.index({tag: 1, letterId: 1, }); sendResultSchema.index({emailId: 1  }); `. Then read up on [indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/). You don't just index on every field and expect it to work, and that applies to every database platform. You actually need to match the selections to the query patterns you use.

Comment: @Neil How does your suggestion perform compared to `.index({ tag: 1, letterId: 1, emailId: -1})`? Asking for a friend... ;)

Comment: @john There's a whole section on "indexes" within the core documentation which I also included a link to. I suggest you read every page. The core thing is that the "query" conditions can only select an index which is "prefixed" with the fields present in the query ( or sort ). Just because an index includes the fields, does not mean it would be selected. My suggestion therefore creates indexes that will be "prefixed" with the fields used. But there's a lot more detail in the manual, and other lengthy blog posts and papers on indexing in general.

Comment: @Neil I might have to have another look then. I was under the impression that the sort field should be included in the index as the last field. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @john Do the reading. Sorting is one of the cases where the query engine can use a different index.

Comment: Links are useful in a post, but **make sure the post is still clear without them**. Instead of linking to the explain output, copy and paste or type it into the post directly.
cf http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: @john Your impression that the sort field should be included in the compound index is correct. Index intersection does not apply when a sort operation requires an index completely separate from the query predicate: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-intersection/#index-intersection-and-sort. The [Optimizing MongoDB Compound Indexes](https://emptysqua.re/blog/optimizing-mongodb-compound-indexes/) blog post is a helpful read. If you have any doubts, confirm the query planner details using [`explain()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/#examples).

Comment: @Neil, I copied db to my laptop. Query executing time is ~1sec I changed indexes as you say, and time decreased to ~0.14sec Thank you!

Comment: Why do you use find( ) with limit 1 instead of find_one( )?

Answer (score 18):

The index would need to cover all part of the query (equality part, sort part, and range part). This is because in a typical `find()` query, MongoDB only uses one index. E.g., it generally doesn't use one index for the equality part, and another index for the sort part.

In general, the sequence of fields in the index needs to follow the pattern of **equality -> sort -> range**.

This is described in detail in [Optimizing MongoDB Compound Indexes](https://emptysqua.re/blog/optimizing-mongodb-compound-indexes/).

For your query, the equality part is `tag:..., letterId:...` and the sort part is `emailId:-1`. There is no range part in your query.

Using this pattern, the compound index you need is:

```
db.test.createIndex({tag:1, letterId:1, emailId:-1})
```

Let's try to confirm how much performance improvement we can get using this index.

#### Test data

To confirm the suitability of the index, I inserted 1 million records into a test database using [mgeneratejs](https://github.com/rueckstiess/mgeneratejs), which is a tool to create a random document using a template.

Based on your example, the `mgeneratejs` template I'm using is:

```
$ cat template.json
{
  "emailId": "$hash",
  "email": "$email",
  "letterId": "$hash",
  "sendedFrom": "$email",
  "resultMsg": "$word",
  "owner": "$name",
  "created": "$date",
  "result": "$bool",
  "tag": "$word",
  "tryNum": {"$integer": {"min": 0, "max": 1e3}},
  "clickHash": "$word",
  "links": {"$array": {"of": "$url", "number": {"$integer": {"min": 1, "max": 5}}}}
}
```

and imported 1 million random documents into MongoDB:

```
$ mgeneratejs template.json -n 1000000 | mongoimport -d test -c test
```

#### Test 1: non-optimal index

Then I create the index you have, and tried to find a non-existent document and gathered 10 runs of the query with the collection containing only this index:

```
> db.test.createIndex({emailId: 1, letterId: 1, result: 1, owner: 1, tag: 1, clickHash: 1})

> db.test.find({"tag" : "xyz", "letterId" : "abc"}).sort({emailId: -1}).limit(1)
Fetched 0 record(s) in 3069ms
Fetched 0 record(s) in 2924ms
Fetched 0 record(s) in 2923ms
Fetched 0 record(s) in 3013ms
Fetched 0 record(s) in 2917ms
Fetched 0 record(s) in 2961ms
Fetched 0 record(s) in 2882ms
Fetched 0 record(s) in 2870ms
Fetched 0 record(s) in 2969ms
Fetched 0 record(s) in 2863ms
```

so using that index, the response times of the query are not great, with most execution close to 3 seconds.

#### Test 2: equality -> sort -> range index

By adding the optimal **equality -> sort -> range** index:

```
> db.test.createIndex({tag:1, letterId:1, emailId:-1})

> db.test.find({"tag" : "xyz", "letterId" : "abc"}).sort({emailId: -1}).limit(1)
Fetched 0 record(s) in 2ms
Fetched 0 record(s) in 1ms
Fetched 0 record(s) in 1ms
Fetched 0 record(s) in 1ms
Fetched 0 record(s) in 1ms
Fetched 0 record(s) in 1ms
Fetched 0 record(s) in 1ms
Fetched 0 record(s) in 1ms
Fetched 0 record(s) in 1ms
Fetched 0 record(s) in 3ms
```

In contrast, using the optimal index, performance was markedly improved. No query returned in more than 3ms, with the great majority of time it returns in 1ms.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need all the fields in the record you can make the query faster by returning just the necessary fields. 
Like;

```
db.sendresults.find({"tag" : "tagValue", "letterId" : "5ad630b5949bb02ea07d15d1"},{"_id":0,"tag":1,"email":1}).sort({emailId: -1}).limit(1)
```

exp. Making field equal to one means returning that field. I made "_id : 0" because I didn't want to get id of the record in mongodb. If you don't add "_id:0" to query it is gonna return the id automatically.

While working with a record with more and nested fields, it saved me a lot of time.